# WPF How to add and perform events on those controls generated during Runtime

Tags: wpf, controls, runtime

For example, I have an empty tabControl in my Windows during the compile time, and I have an undetermined amount of images need to be added onto the tabControl, so I used loop + tabControl.Children.Add("image1 to x") to add those images... but after that during runtime, I want to perform events on those image controls, such as dragging the image from the tabControl to another Panel. Is it possible to do so? If it's possible, how?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood what exactly you want, but if you want to add an event handler for a control in runtime, you can do that like the following sample:

```
Image i = new Image();
i.Click += (sender,e) => { [write here your code] };
```

for drag and drop, you can see the [thumb](http://dvuyka.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!305B02907E9BE19A!155.entry?sa=216940413) control, It might help you